# Call method through interface without creating a new instance of the interface

Tags: c#, .net, object, interface

What I am trying to do is actually really simple, but for some reason I am either going the wrong way about it or am just missing some vital know how, because I just cannot figure out how to call a method through an interface without creating a new instance of the class/interface.

Either way, what I am trying to achieve is to call the following method through an interface that implements the method, without having to create a new instance.

```
public partial class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
   public void MyMethod(object obj)
   {
      //Method code....
   }
 }
```

my interface

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
   void MyMethod(object obj);
}
```

My Solution has three Projects

- Data
- Service
- UI

the Interface and `MyClass.xaml.cs` are in the UI, and I am trying to call the `MyMethod()` method from a class in my Service layer by using an existing instance of the interface.

I have done it like this from another section in the code which does not work here, I have no idea why

```
//Register interface
internal static IMyInterface mi;
//and call it like so
mi.MyMethod(Object);
```

I have done plenty of google searches, but everyone seems to create a new instance which in my case is not a valid option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> by using an existing instance of the interface.

So, if you have created one instance of MyClass class, you could implement [Singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650849.aspx) for it [like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx). So, your single instance would be available everywhere.

For example:

```
public partial class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    private static IMyInterface _instance;

    public static IMyInterface Instance
    { 
        get 
        {
            if (_instance == null) _instance = new MyClass();
            return _instance;
        }
    }
    public void MyMethod(object obj)
    {
       //Method code....
    }
}
```

And

```
//Register interface
internal static IMyInterface mi = MyClass.Instance;
//and call it like so
mi.MyMethod(Object);
```

Answer (score 3):

> what i am trying to achieve is to call the following method through an
>   interface that implements the method, without having to create a new
>   instance

***interface that implements the method*** - is a wrong assumption. Interface never implements the method. It just says whoever implements this interface should implement that method.

The class who implements your interface - in your case `MyClass`. You need to create an instance of it.

```
internal IMyInterface mi = new MyClass();
mi.MyMethod(Object);
```

There is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

You can not create an instance of interface. You can access an object via the interfaces it implements. For example if you have a `List<T>` you can access it via `IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, 
IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Interfaces does not have any code or any implementation. You define an interface like `IFruit` which has `Color` and `Taste` property and `Eat` method but you do not implement anything in it. When you say `Red Apple` class is implementing `IFruit` then you implement the properties and method in that class.

In another word you can access objects through interfaces. You must have an object behind the interface.

Comment: I don't see an answer on the OP: how to call the method without create an instance (of object). Is one thing to say what you **can not** do, but a little bit harder to answer what you actually **can** do...

Answer (score 0):

Going to Necro this.

I am going to offer an alternative approach/path that provides a different approach to implementing and execution of the Interface

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DydxUN) (Included Content in the event the Short URL is purged)

### Setup

#### Interface

```
public interface IMyInterface{
    void MyMethod();
}
```

#### Class

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface{
    // Implicit Implementation
    public void MyMethod(){
        Console.WriteLine("* Entered the Implicit Interface Method");

        (this as IMyInterface).MyMethod();
    }

    // Explicit Implementation
    void IMyInterface.MyMethod(){
        Console.WriteLine("--> Entered the Explicit Interface Method");
    }
}
```

### Execution

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var cl = new MyClass();

        Console.WriteLine("Executing method off Object");
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");

        cl.MyMethod();

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Executing method through Casting");
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");

        (cl as IMyInterface).MyMethod();

    }
}
```

### Results

```
Executing method off Object
--------------------------------
* Entered the Implicit Interface Method
--> Entered the Explicit Interface Method


Executing method through Casting
--------------------------------
--> Entered the Explicit Interface Method
```